# UITapGestureRecognizer selector not working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I make UITableView with custom UITableViewCell.
I put one UITextField in my UITableViewCell also I add UITapGestureRecognizer to my UITableView that get CGPoint.y when tap one any cell.

**!!!my problem here!!!**
when I focus on UITextField in any cell my UITapGestureRecognizer selector **not working**!!! but when I tap any where on cell except UITextField UITapGestureRecognizer selector working!!!

I want when focus in UITextField UITapGestureRecognizer selector working and I get point.y of screen!!!

this is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.prsnTable];    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tpgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapPress:)];
    [self.prsnTable addGestureRecognizer:tpgr];

}
- (void)handleTapPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.prsnTable];
    NSLog(@"%f",p.y);
}
- (UITableView*)prsnTable {
    if (!_prsnTable) {
        CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-70);
        _prsnTable =[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _prsnTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
        _prsnTable.delegate = self;
        _prsnTable.dataSource = self;
        _prsnTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        [_prsnTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        _prsnTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        _prsnTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
    }
    return _prsnTable;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SourCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[SourCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SourCell"];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    MFTextField *tfName = (MFTextField*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    tfName.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TextField Delegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"focus");
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"aaaaaa");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UITextField won't pass touches to a UIGestureRecognizer unless you have set the property userInteractionEnabled = YES.